# Alternating grid colours in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this CSS grid, and I'd like to alternate the grid colors in a checkerboard pattern. Here's the HTML/CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #578a34
        }

        #game-board {
            background-color: #aad751;
            width: 100vmin;
            height: 100vmin;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(21, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
        }

        .dark-tile {
            background-color: #a2d149;
        }

        .light-tile {
            background-color: #aad751;
        }

        .snake {
            background-color: #4e7cf6;
        }

        .food {
            background-color: #e7471d;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="game.js" defer type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-board">
    <div style="grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 11;" class="snake"></div>
    <div style="grid-row-start: 7; grid-column-start: 14;" class="food"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I managed to make something of a checkerboard pattern: [image]

However, it gets messed up around where the food and the snake is. I suspect this is due to `.appendChild(tile)`. Here's the code for drawing the checkerboard:

```js
export function draw(gameBoard) {
    for (let j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE+1; j++){
        for (let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE+1; i++){
            if (Math.abs(i % 2) == 1){
                const tile = document.createElement('div')
                tile.classList.add('dark-tile')
                gameBoard.appendChild(tile)
            } else {
                const tile = document.createElement('div')
                tile.classList.add('light-tile')
                gameBoard.appendChild(tile)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any HTML elements that have either class `food` or `snake`. Are they appended through JS? If so, just make sure you assign a class to them before appending them to the DOM and your CSS should do the rest

Comment: Yes, they are appended through JavaScript. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You should open your console after the board renders and copy that HTML and paste it in your question.

Comment: Okay, I've done that. Thanks!

Comment: Right now you only have 2 items in your grid, the snake and the food. You have to fill in all the other locations in the grid in order to have elements to attach your checkerboard styling to.  Or you could use a background image.